# How can I download a complete TekPub-series without clicking on each episode?

Tags: bulk-download

I have an annual subscription to [TekPub](http://tekpub.com/) and want to download a complete series without having to click on each episode and then use the download-link. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't have a subscription, so I can't find out: can you provide an example of a link? If they only change the numbers, it's easy to mass download them using [DownThemAll's batch downloads](http://www.downthemall.net/howto/help/english-menu/batch-downloadsbatch-descriptors/).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it doesn't look like this is possible.

<strike>This has already been [raised as an idea on the TekPub](http://support.tekpub.com/tekpub/topics/easy_download_all_videos_in_a_series) forums so maybe you could like the idea and follow it's progress.</strike> 
This topic seems to have been removed.